# How do I find all possible permutations with multiple "holes" in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I have the following initial string:

```
initial = "S + B + B"
```

and a dictionary consisting of possible replacements:

```
replacements = { "S": ["0", "1"], "B": ["a", "b", "1"] }
```

and I want to write a function `permute` that creates all possible permutations given the acceptable replacements:

```
def permute(initial, replacements):
    pass  # TODO

print(permute(initial, replacements))
```

which should output the following:

```
["0 + a + a", "1 + a + a", "0 + a + b", ...]
```

A few caveats:

- The replacements are guaranteed to have the keys if they are found in the initial string (eg. the situation where "S" is in initial but not a key in the replacement dict will *not* occur)
- The replacement dict values may be of any length greater than or equal to 1 (ie. non-empty)
- I'm looking for any answers compatible with Python 3 => 3.7 or so

I'm attempting to write this to use in a [program synthesis approach](http://people.csail.mit.edu/asolar/SynthesisCourse/Lecture3.htm) (the grow step) but I'm having difficulty translating it to Python. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @DeepSpace I think you're right, I'm going to remove the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools as it, re
initial = "S + B + B"
replacements = { "S": ["0", "1"], "B": ["a", "b", "1"] }
r = [re.sub('\w+', '{}', initial).format(*i) for i in it.product(*[replacements[i] for i in re.findall('\w+', initial)])]
```

Output:

```
['0 + a + a', '0 + a + b', '0 + a + 1', '0 + b + a', '0 + b + b', '0 + b + 1', '0 + 1 + a', '0 + 1 + b', '0 + 1 + 1', '1 + a + a', '1 + a + b', '1 + a + 1', '1 + b + a', '1 + b + b', '1 + b + 1', '1 + 1 + a', '1 + 1 + b', '1 + 1 + 1']
```